# Increasing Sequence C++

Tags: c++, c++11, sequence

I try to solve this challenge on CodeFights, but, it doesn't work. My best solution got 25/26 (time limit exceeded on the last test) but I deleted that because I tried it yesterday (it was O(n^2)). Now I tried a new one in O(n). I am very tired and I really want to get this done today, so please help me.

Here are the statements:
Given a sequence of integers as an array, determine whether it is possible to obtain a strictly increasing sequence by removing no more than one element from the array.

Example

```
For sequence = [1, 3, 2, 1], the output should be
almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = false;

There is no one element in this array that can be removed in order to get a strictly increasing sequence.

For sequence = [1, 3, 2], the output should be
almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = true.

You can remove 3 from the array to get the strictly increasing sequence [1, 2]. Alternately, you can remove 2 to get the strictly increasing sequence [1, 3].
```

And here is my code until now... (poor code):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <algorithm>

bool almostIncreasingSequence(std::vector<int> sequence) 
{
    int count = 0;


    for(int i = 0; i < sequence.size()-1; i++)
    {
        if(sequence[i] > sequence[i+1])
        {
            count++;
            sequence.erase(sequence.begin(), sequence.begin() + i);
            i--;
        }
        if(count == 2)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code does (almost) nothing at the moment as the `almostIncreasingSequence` function is not called.

Comment: This is not important in challenge, i must write only function, main and headers are automatically added :) I write main + headers because i want to keep this files in my PC

Comment: Please do not link to websites that require logons or navigation to your code. What does this problem statement say?

Comment: Added, sorry :) didn't know that it require to login for statements

Comment: *I am very tired and I really want to get this done today* -- This will not get you "expedited help".  Not getting enough sleep is *your* issue, and is not relevant.

Comment: Why are you erasing anything from the vector? That's an expensive operation (and should not be necessary).

Comment: Also, your test `sequence[i] > sequence[i+1]` is incorrect. The problem says strictly increasing.

Comment: well, yes. and if s[i] > s[i+1] that is not increasing sequence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a C++11 solution with O(N) runtime:

```
constexpr auto Max = std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max();
bool is_sorted_but_skip(const std::vector<int>& vec, std::size_t index = Max){
    auto Start = index == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    auto prev = vec[Start];
    for(std::size_t i = Start + 1; i < vec.size(); i++){
        if(i == index) continue;
        if(prev >= vec[i]) return false;
        prev = vec[i];
    }
    return true;
}

bool almostIncreasingSequence(std::vector<int> v) 
{
    auto iter = std::adjacent_find(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int L, int R){ return L >= R; });
    if(is_sorted_but_skip(v, std::distance(v.begin(), iter)))
        return true;
    return is_sorted_but_skip(v, std::distance(v.begin(), std::next(iter)));
}
```

We use [`std::adjacent_find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted_until) to find the first element, `iter` greater than or equal its next element. Then we check that sequence is strictly sorted while skipping `iter`'s position.

Otherwise, we check that the sequence is strictly sorted while we skip `iter+1`'s position

Worse case complexity: 3 linear scan

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c78d72622099267)

Comment: only one more step needed: you said "to find first element greater", but we need "to find first element greater or equal"

Comment: @Vader, I didn't read the part of "strictly increasing" in your question. That will require significant changes to this code. Gimme a few minutes

Comment: It looks like compiler have some problems with line 5 with size_t and auto:file.cpp on line 5:17: error: invalid operands of types 'std::size_t {aka long unsigned int}' and '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to binary 'operator=='
         if(i == index) continue;

Comment: You don't declare that index, what is with this variable?

Answer (score 0):

This is still O(N^2), because you delete the first element of the vector in each iteration. Don't delete the first element and don't `i--` in the loop.

If you *must* erase the numbers (you don't, but still), at least do it from the end of the list. That way erasing a number is *probably* an O(1) operation (I'm not 100% sure that's how std::vector is implemented).

You really don't have to erase the numbers.

Comment: Would you erase numbers from the list if you did this with pencil and paper?  Or would you just record that a "bad number" was encountered, skip over it, and keep going until you hit another "bad number"?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint (well, almost a solution really):

**If you see a decrease between one element to the next, then you have to remove one of them (*).**

Now, what if you find two decreases, between two disjoint pairs of elements? That's right :-)

Keeping that in mind, you should be able to solve your problem using a linear scan and a bit of constant-time work.

<sub>(*) excluding the first and the last pair of elements.</sub>

Comment: For 2 decreases => return false because we can remove only one element

Comment: @Vader: Yes - the point is that with a linear scan you can limit your can rule this out, and at the same time mark a very small number of places of potential removals. Then you check those out.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int almostIncreasingSequence( vector<int> sequence );

int main(){
    int array[] = {40, 50, 60, 10, 20, 30};
    std::vector<int> vect (array, array + sizeof(array) / sizeof(int) );
    bool ret = almostIncreasingSequence(vect);

    if( ret ){
        std::cout<<"Array is strictly increasing.";
    }
    else{
std::cout<<"Array is not strictly increasing.";
    }
    return 0;
}
bool almostIncreasingSequence(std::vector<int> sequence) {
    int val = 0;
    int currentBig = sequence.at(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < sequence.size(); i++){
        if( currentBig < sequence.at(i))
        {
            currentBig = sequence.at(i);
        }
        else{
            val++;
            if( val>1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if( i > 1 ){
                if (sequence.at(i) > sequence.at(i-2)){
                    if( currentBig < sequence.at(i) ){
                    }
                    else{
                        currentBig = sequence.at(i);
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                currentBig = sequence.at(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```